# VBA Run macro with arguments from Command Button click in UserForm

Tags: vba, excel

I have a UserForm *DataInput* in the same VBA project as the module *RunOB*. These are in the Excel Project *Benchmarking.xlsx*. I have a command button on the *DataInput* form in which I would like the module *RunOB* to run when pressed. Additionally I am passing String arguments from the form to the module.

```
'Header of 'Run OB' Module
Sub OrganizeBenchmarks(bidNum As String, name As String, _
                       state As String, year As String, category As String)
```

The button click method is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '...'
End Sub
```

<s>If possible, it would also be helpful if I could set up a keyboard shortcut to open the *DataInput* UserForm while I was in the Excel project.</s>

Comment: in Workbook_Open, put something like `Application.OnKey "^+{LEFT}", "OrganizeBenchmarks" - this is to use Ctrl-Shift-LeftArrow`; and in Workbook_BeforeClose, put `Application.OnKey "^+{LEFT}"` to disable it

Comment: @Guest if you're running it via key shortcuts, how does it resolve the input parameters?

Comment: Like a commandbutton, you can not send parameters to a keyboard shortcut. In the past, I always resolved that situation (when someone absolutely wants a keyboard shortcut) by calling a sub with no parameters that calls the sub with parameters that you need. Then, the parameters have to be either global or set as part of the called sub. Nothing is perfect.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 - if I load in the UserForm via a keyboard shortcut, I planned to enter the data on the form then run the macro when I hit the submit button on the form. The data that was input on the form should resolve the input parameters.

Comment: @Guest - is there a way to load the OrganizeBenchmarks macro with the parameters from the DataInput form if you just scrap the keyboard shortcut part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    OrganizeBenchmarks "your", "arguments", "would", "go", "here"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something for you to help developing your own code .........

```
'Public enum type to add a set of particular vbKeys to the standard key set
Public Enum typePressKeys
    vbNoKey = 0
    vbExitTrigger = -1
    vbAnswerKey = 100
    vbLaunchKey = 102
    vbPrevious = 104
    vbNext = 106
    vbSpecialAccessKey = 108
End Enum


Public Sub OrganizeBenchmarks()
Dim stopLoop As Boolean, listOfYears As Variant, bidNum As String, name As String, state As String, year As String, category As String

'For example
listOfYears = Array(2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022)

stopLoop = False
Load DataInputForm 'Assuming this is the name of your UserForm
With DataInputForm 'Assuming that this name would be an input control in your UserForm
    .yearCB.List = listOfYears 'comboboxList control
    .yearCB.ListIndex = 2
    .Tag = vbNoKey
End With
DataInputForm.Show
Do
    If DataInputForm.Tag = vbOK Then
        'I have assumed you would use these names for input controls on your UserForm
        bidNum = DataInputForm.bidNum_TextBox.Value
        name = DataInputForm.name_TextBox.Value
        state = DataInputForm.state_TextBox.Value
        year = CStr(DataInputForm.yearCB.Value)
        category = DataInputForm.category_TextBox.Value
        Unload DataInputForm
        stopLoop = True
    ElseIf DataInputForm.Tag = vbCancel Then
        Unload DataInputForm
        Exit Sub
    Else
        stopLoop = False
    End If
Loop Until stopLoop = True

'Place additional code here to take whatever actions 

End Sub
```